# Package list file lists the wrong version of MySQL

Tags: mysql

ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.list in http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/ubuntu/releases/14.04.1/ lists version 5.5.38 of MySQL server (/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb); but this version is not there in http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/. So, MySQL cannot be installed through apt-get.

How can I solve this issue? Assume that I cannot change the /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Is this an official mirror? In any case: select a different mirror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an issue. The listing in the first link is for the contents of the Ubuntu 14.04.1 ISO, and doesn't have anything to do with the contents of a mirror (the second link).